# Plot not drawn in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, version, billboard.js

After updating my `rmarkdown`, my plots are not drawn anymore. I can see the plots if I run them locally and I can also plot with alternative plotting packages like `ggplot2`.

This is an example code:

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(billboarder)
library(data.table)
```

### Chart A

```{r}
billboarder() %>%
  bb_piechart(as.data.table(mtcars)[, .N, by=.(am)], bbaes(am, N))
```
````

When I knit this documents I get the following html file:

[image]

This is how it looks when I run the plot in R:

[image]

And this is a working `ggplot` alternative:

[image]

Is this something that can be solved or do I need to wait on the plotting package to be updated? I could try downgrading my `rmarkdown` package but I am not certain if that will solve the issue nor to which version I should go back to. Maybe someone that is more experienced with the backend of `rmarkdown` knows what update could cause this to happen, I unfortunately do not know which `rmarkdown` version I was running before updating.

Comment: Your example works nice on my PC. If you knit to pdf - same problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot knit to pdf on my workstation because of the LateX dependency. Could you share with me the versions of R and Rmarkdown you are using?

Comment: R - 4.1.0, Rstudio - 1.4.1106. RMarkdown - 2.11